# How do I add parfor in algorithmic environment?

Tags: formatting, indentation, loops

I want to have a **parfor** loop in my algorithm listing (it should work exactly as standard **for** loop works). How to either change the displayed name of for loop or add my own loop which will keep the indents?

Comment: Doesn't stating it is a parallel loop nullify the *pseudo* aspect of `algorithmic`? Do you perhaps need `listings` or some variant for code inclusion?

Comment: How about the pseudocodes of parallel algorithms? These are not the implementations (listings) but the concepts.

Comment: I consider `parfor` to be a Matlab feature, with a certain set of conditions on side-effects etc. An algorithm doesn't become a parallel algorithm just because some loop is executed in parallel. A (bad) solution: edit algorithmic.sty, adding `  \newcommand{\PARFOR}[2][default]{\ALC@it\algorithmicparfor\ ##2\ \algorithmicdo%
\ALC@com{##1}\begin{ALC@for}}` and `\newcommand{\algorithmicparfor}{\textbf{parfor}}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [algorithmicx](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx) package to define a new block that behaves as the standard `\For` loop; a little example (using `algpseudocode`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}

% declaration of the new block
\algblock{ParFor}{EndParFor}
% customising the new block
\algnewcommand\algorithmicparfor{\textbf{parfor}}
\algnewcommand\algorithmicpardo{\textbf{do}}
\algnewcommand\algorithmicendparfor{\textbf{end\ parfor}}
\algrenewtext{ParFor}[1]{\algorithmicparfor\ #1\ \algorithmicpardo}
\algrenewtext{EndParFor}{\algorithmicendparfor}

\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\For{$i\gets 1, n$}
  \State $sum\gets sum+i$
\EndFor
\ParFor{$j\gets 1, m$}
  \State $prod\gets prod*j$
  \ParFor{$k\gets 1, p$}
    \State $fact\gets fact*k$
  \EndParFor
\EndParFor
\end{algorithmic}

\end{document}
```

[image]